# SortDescriptions

Tags: c#, wpf, sorting, combobox

I'm using c# in combination of WPF.

I've used a `CollectionView` with a single `SortDescription`. But in certain cases the `SortDescription` is not used. Yet I couldn't find out why this is happening.

The `ComboBox` isn't sorted for some reason. When I add a second `SortDescription` with the same sorting option it also happens.

No `cv.sortdescriptions.clear();` is used for this particular `SortDescription`.
In 99% of the cases it works perfect, but somehow for one reason yet this happening.

Anyone have a clue?

Comment: try to refresh the view after collection changes (CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(SomeCollection).Refresh())

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as a side note, it would be more performant to use the CustomSort property.  Apparently the SortDescriptions uses reflection, so for large sets of data, it is unacceptably slow.

[check this blog for more information](http://ligao101.wordpress.com/2007/07/31/a-much-faster-sorting-for-listview-in-wpf/)

Answer (score 3):

What is the type of the property you're sorting on?

WPF's SortDescription only sorts on properties that implement [IComparable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable.aspx). Note that implementing [IComparable<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d7sx9hd.aspx) isn't enough - you need to explicitly implement the non-generic interface.

Comment: That's for sure, but the sortdescription does work in 99% of the cases. And isn't changed by code. I can't this issue in the programming environment or in the test environment. 

but the customer has this issue. And even the customer can't find this issue. It happens at strange moments, and the variables are always the same.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the type of collection, it's possible that your [CollectionView.CanSort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionview.cansort.aspx) is false.  In this case, sorting will not work, and the SortDescription will be ignored.

Comment: Yet I had checked that, and that isn't changed in code or automatically.